# Efficient comparison of all dataframe fields with the lag of all fields in pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

My question is about Pyspark.

In my DataFrame I have a lag field which is created as follows

`    my_columns = df_source.columns
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('start_dt')

```
 df_source = df_source.withColumn('LAG', f.array(*[f.lag(c).over(window_spec) for c in                                          my_columns])`
```

How can I efficiently compare each original field of a df_source with the lag of each field stored in the LAG array?

I think it can be done something like this, but I'm not sure if it will work correctly and this is definitely not a optimized way

```
`df_source = df_source.withColumn('COMPARE', f.array(*[f.lag(c).over(window_spec ) for c in                                           my_columns]) == f.array(*[my_columns])).filter(f.col('COMPARE') == False)`
```

As a result of the comparison, I need to understand that at least one field does not match the lag.

Ideally, check fields until the first mismatch.
If there is at least one mismatch I need to return False if all fields match True.

Null values ​​must be considered equal.

Null values  and not Null ​​must be considered not equal.

For example:

[image]

Comment: @ Anthony are you using azure